# SQL DB Diagram to cooperate cost to customer with temp time discounts

Tags: sql, database, diagram, pos

I am moving a POS (Point of sale) and inventory management DB in my spare time.

This is the diagram i have so far to track the goods movement.

[image: Goods movement diag]

My two questions are:

---

Q1: 
Is what i have so far the most efficient way to do this?

---

Q2: 
How do i incorporate a cost to customer and cost to business (Depending if its an in or out movement of stock) while allowing for temp promotions and discounts?

Additional Details:
MSSQL Server 2014
MSSQL Management 2014
Program will eventually be written in C# (if it makes a difference)

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Q1 is completely dependent on your end goal. Q2, you'll need to design a "price list" schema of some kind, and also handle the accounting side of things. Which is kind of out of scope for a SO post...